# View comes back blank (uses a subquery to filter balance column)

Tags: sql, view, syntax

I am trying to get back some data from the balance column using a subquery but it seems as though the data comes back with nothing, not even any ids when doing this. If I do a simple query it is fine but I am trying to filter my data so that only a select number of rows are selected. This query should work:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerDebt as
select id, 
balance from (
    SELECT
    Ca.id,
    (sum(Ca.DebitAmount) - sum(Ca.Creditamount)) as [balance]
    FROM
    CustomerAccount Ca 
    GROUP BY id) 
    as debt
where balance < 0
```

This is the query that works without using the subquery but includes all ids with 0 as well as the balances which is what I do not want:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerDebt as
SELECT
Ca.Customerid,
(sum(Ca.DebitAmount) - sum(Ca.Creditamount)) as [balance]

FROM
CustomerAccount Ca

GROUP BY
Ca.Customerid
```

If I could have an explanation as to why it doesn't work, maybe it is a semantic error or something (I am new to this stuff).

Answer (score 1):

You are simply missing the HAVING-clause(the WHERE for groups):

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerDebt as
SELECT Ca.Customerid,
     (sum(Ca.DebitAmount) - sum(Ca.Creditamount)) as [balance]
FROM CustomerAccount Ca
GROUP BY Ca.Customerid
HAVING (sum(Ca.DebitAmount) - sum(Ca.Creditamount)) < 0
```

The 'error' in your other view is probably the use of the column `id` where `CustomerId` is meant...